# Create JTable header without using new JTable(data,columnNames)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, columnheader

I've read how to create a `JTable` on `JScrollPane` with data in code, but how can I create a empty table with column header without adding data to it?

I want to add data to it from a form - not from my code.

Comment: *"..how can I create a empty table with column header without adding data to it?"* Design the headers and columns of a `TableModel` .. with **no data.** For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your attempt.

Comment: E.G. `String[] columnIDs = {"First", "Last"}; DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnIDs, 0);
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));` See [How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for details.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Netbeans for Development, it will be quite easy to work with  JTables.

Using Netbeans, simply select Table from the palate and put it wherever you wish it to display.

Then in properties, you can change column names, add new columns and delete older. Also there only you will get an option of rows to display, simply put that to zero (0).

Voila! Your table is ready with column names and No Rows.